# Calling to a method from ForEach doesn't working properly - vue.js

Tags: vue.js, foreach

I'm trying to call a method from a `foreach` in vue, but the method is performed only one time,

No matter how many variables are in the list.

attached here the two functions I used:

```js
CleanChips() {
    this.chips.forEach((item) => {
      this.RemoveRequirement(item)
    })
  },
  RemoveRequirement(item) {
    var index = this.chips.indexOf(item);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.chips.splice(index, 1);
      this.chips = [...this.chips];
    }
  },
```

The RemoveRequirement function is performed only one time.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: I believe this has to do with the fact that you are editing this.chips from within the foreach loop. Can you try storing the result in another variable in the RemoveRequirement() method to see if the result if the same?

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer :). I tried already what you said and it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You modify the array itself in `RemoveRequirement` while running through it in `CleanChips`. You should create a copy of the original array to iterate in order to safely delete elements in the original array.

```
CleanChips() {
    const chipsCopy = [...this.chips]
    chipsCopy.forEach((item) => {
      this.RemoveRequirement(item)
    })
  },
  RemoveRequirement(item) {
    var index = this.chips.indexOf(item);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.chips.splice(index, 1);
      // this.chips = [...this.chips]; // you don't need this line because `splice` is reactivity-compatible.
    }
  },
```